# Anagram problems

Tags: c, anagram

I'm new to this forum and would like to seek help. I'm trying to modify an anagram program based on code from http://www.sanfoundry.com/c-program-...ings-anagrams/.
This time, however, I have used array pointers to obtain input from the user. I have also created a function "check_input" to ensure that the input consists of ONLY characters and excludes symbols(!, #, $). However, when I ran the program, it still accepts those symbols and does not break like I wanted it to. Please help.

Plus, I intend to make the program treat upper-case letters the same way as lower-case letters. Can this be achieved by using the "stricmp" function? If so, where should I place that function? Alternative methods are also appreciated.

## Update: Sorry. I've added the check_input code at the bottom.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>


int test_anagram(char *ptrArray1, char *ptrArray2);
int check_input(char array1[], char array2[]);

int main()
{
char array1[100], array2[100];
char *pArray1, *pArray2;
int flag;

pArray1 = array1;
pArray2 = array2;

printf("Enter the first word: \n");
gets(pArray1);

printf("Enter the second word: \n");
gets(pArray2);

check_input(pArray1, pArray2);

flag = test_anagram(pArray1, pArray2);
if(flag == 1){
    printf("\"%s\" and \"%s\" are anagrams.\n", pArray1,    pArray2);
}else{
    printf("\"%s\" and \"%s\" are not anagrams.\n", pArray1, pArray2);
}

return 0;
}

int test_anagram(char array1[], char array2[])
{
int num1[26] = {0}, num2[26] = {0}, i = 0;

while(array1[i] != '\0')
{
    num1[array1[i] - 'a']++;
    i++;
}

i = 0;
while(array2[i] != '\0')
{
    num2[array2[i] - 'a']++;
    i++;
}

for(i=0;i<26;i++)
{
    if(num1[i] != num2[i]){
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}


}

int check_input(char array1[], char array2[])
{
while(isalpha((int)array1) != 1){
    break;
}

while(isalpha((int)array2) != 1){
    break;
}
}
```

Comment: Post the code for your `check_input` function.

Comment: Two things: First is that `gets` have long been deprecated, and even removed from the latest C standard, it's unsafe and should not be used. Secondly, your pointer `pArray1` and `pArray2` are redundant. Arrays decays to pointers anyway when you pass them to functions, and in other cases too, so your pointer variables aren't needed.

Comment: As for your problem, look closes at the last loop in the `test_anagram` function, are you sure you want the `return 1;` statement where you have put it? I suggest you step though that loop line by line in a debugger.

Comment: @REACHUS

I've added the code for check_input.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg

I've added the code for check_input.

Comment: And your `check_input` is as wrong as it could be, it checks that the *pointer* is a letter. It also have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) since it doesn't return a value, not that you check the returned value anyway, so there really is no validation of the input.

Comment: @lcm your question appear to be unsolved because you havent accepted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't (yet) posted the full code of the `check_input()` function but one advice would be to validate the input when the user inputs every character.

You can do this using f.e. the `getchar()` function and checking if the inputted character is a letter, as well as converting it to the lowercase (or uppercase if you will).

You can do lowercase convertion like this:

```
#include <ctype.h>

// ...
tolower('A');
```